# Show that the equivalence problem for deterministic Turing machines and its complement is not semi-decidable

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I would like to show that 
$$EQ_{DTM} = \{ (\langle M_1\rangle,\langle M_2\rangle) \mid M_1\text{ and } M_2 \text{ are  DTMs  and } L(M_1)=L(M_2)\}$$
 and 
$$\overline{EQ_{DTM}}$$
 are not semi-decidable. I think there must be a reduction from the complement of the halting problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier way to approach this is by reducing from
$$ALL_{TM}=\{\langle M \rangle: M \text{ is a DTM and } L(M)=\Sigma^*\}$$

Showing that $ALL_{TM}$ is not in in RE nor coRE a standard exercise, and you can find the solution e.g. [here](http://moodle.cs.huji.ac.il/cs12/mod/resource/view.php?id=4423)

Then, we can reduce from $ALL_{TM}$ to $EQ_{TM}$ as follows: given input $\langle{M\rangle}$ for $ALL_{TM}$, we output $\langle{M,T\rangle}$ where $T$ is a fixed TM that accepts every input immediately. Thus, $L(T)=\Sigma^*$, and we have that $L(M)=L(T)$ iff $L(M)=\Sigma^*$, so the reduction is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first point is clear to me, but the second (the "easy exercise") is not. I'm not very familiar with reducing and need some help.

Comment: Added the reduction.

Comment: Looking up Rice's theorem would probably be a good start if you're not familiar with reductions. Basically any question about the language accepted by a Turing machine is undecidable.

Comment: @jmite - the OP needs to show a language that is not in RE nor in coRE. Rice's theorem won't suffice here.

Comment: It's not enough but it's a good start, especially for the "easy exercise" part he's talking about

Comment: I think that didactically, Rice's theorem is not a good tool to study reductions. It ``hides'' the nature of reductions, and the proof itself gives only little insight as to the relevant tricks that are used in reductions (in an undergrad course). But I guess that's a different discussion, and at any rate - I completely agree it's a useful theorem to know.

Comment: @Shaull: I'd like to say a big thank you to you. Your explanations helped me very much.